# Autohotkey: Hotkeys on Firefox not doing what they're supposed to

Tags: firefox, autohotkey

I just want **W** to correspond to the **Up Arrow** key and **S** to correspond to the **Down Arrow** key, and work just like they do, and for **A/D** to move the focus to the last/next tab.

When i hold **S**, the page skips down erratically and then Firefox opens the "Save as" window multiple times.

When i hold **W**, the page skips up erratically and then multiple tabs are closed.

**D** does what it's supposed to, and **A** straight up doesn't work.

```
    #IfWinActive ahk_exe firefox.exe

    w::
    Send {Up}  ; Move page up.

    s::
    send {down} ; Move page down.

    a::
    send, ^{pgup} ; Go to tab on the left.

    d::
    send, ^{pgdn} ; Go to tab on the right.

    #IfWinActive

    Return
```

What exactly is happening? It should work normally but it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe firefox.exe

    w:: Send {Up}       ; Move page up.
    s:: send {down}     ; Move page down.

#IfWinActive    ; turn off context sensitivity
```

The above examples are known as **single-line hotkeys** because each consists of only one command.

To have **more than one command executed by a hotkey**, put the first line beneath the hotkey definition and make the last line a **return**. For example:

```
#n::
Run http://www.google.com
Run Notepad.exe
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Intro

Comment: It's working now. Thanks, wow... I would have edited my last comment but i can't.